# kafka-connect-elasticsearch: how to send deletes of documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a processing stream that looks like this:

```
mysql.database -> debezium-connector -> database topic -> faust.agent(stream processing to add a field) -> sink topic -> elasticsearch-sink-connector -> elasticsearch cluster
```

This processing stream is working for the most part, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle deleted row events coming from the database topic. As in if a row gets deleted I want it to also be removed from elasticsearch. I can use a conditional in the faust section that could manipulate the event. Is there a way to mark an event so that when it's picked up by the elasticsearch-sink-connector it removes a given document instead of adding it? I've looked through the documentation, but I don't see specifics on this. Is the sink connector meant only to add documents to an index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [config for the connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/configuration_options.html#configuration-properties) it looks like you can set `behavior.on.null.values` to `delete`. Then you just need to make sure you set a tombstone (null) against keys for which the document should be deleted.

Debezium will [by default](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/0.10/connectors/mysql.html) generate tombstone messages for deletes.